# Laravel Insert/Update/Delete

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have this code below, however when adding around 2000 rows this runs too slow due to being in an foreach loop.

```
foreach($tables as $key => $table) {

    $class_name = explode("\\", get_class($table[0]));
    $class_name = end($class_name);

    $moved = 'moved_' . $class_name;
    ${$moved} = [];

    foreach($table[0]->where('website_id', $website->id)->get() as $value) {
        $value->website_id = $live_website_id;
        $value->setAppends([]);
        $table[0]::on('live')->updateOrCreate([
            'id' => $value->id,
            'website_id' => $value->website_id
        ], $value->toArray());
        ${$moved}[] = $value->id;
    }

    // Remove deleted rows
    if ($table[1]) {
        $table[0]::on('live')->where([ 'website_id' => $live_website_id ])
            ->whereNotIn('id', ${$moved})
            ->delete();
    }
}
```

What is happening is basically users will add/update/delete data in a development server, then when they hit a button this data needs to be pushed into the live table, retaining the ID's as auto incremental id's on the live won't work due to look-up tables and multiple users launching data live at the same time.

What is the best way to do this? Should I simply remove all the data in that table (there is a unique identifier for chunks of data) and then just insert?

Comment: Does the feedback need to be inmediate? If not you can use queues https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

Comment: @namelivia the user could wait, just thinking the way i'm doing it above is intensive on the server? Is there a way to display a progress bar?

Comment: It's not very easy to add a progress bar to a client-side browser when you're doing a server-side operation no. You could potentially provide updates by flushing some output to the browser at regular intervals (I don't know how well that works with Laravel's MVC engine though). But generally long-running jobs like this are far better handed off to a background service, and then the user be notified of completion separately (e.g. by visiting a status page, or getting an email - or you might be able to do something using websockets). This avoids issues with timeouts, lack of feedback etc

Comment: I though it might be a bit difficult @ADyson, thanks. I think I might be safer to just delete the data and then insert as this operation is almost instant and the ID's should remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I ended up just deleting the rows and then re-inserting them. Worked out being quicker, less intensive and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think can do:

- You can create a temp table and fill just like your development server and just rename table to published table
- Use Job and background service(async queue)
- You can set your db connection as singleton, because connecting multiple times can waste time
- Can use some sql tools for example if use postgresql you can use Foreign Data Wrapper(fdw) to connect db to each other and update and create in a faster way!